# Handling Http Post and Get in the same view - ASP.Net MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My view has 2 label 2 text-boxes and a button.

**This is my controller :**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // Custom model that holds values
    // this is to set the default values to the text boxes

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CustomModel viewModel )
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here

        // The  button should trigger this method to   perform  update  

        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I run the program it automatically goes to my model which contains no value and throws a null pointer exception. Any ideas on how to preserve the model state. ?

**Update :**

I am  using classic ADO.Net Model not the entity framework.

The `http get` and the `post method` follows a different logic. The Model with values are returned using the get method and the state of this model needs to be preserved for updating the corresponding records to the database using the post method.

But, when I use the post method, the compiler automatically routes to my model class looking for a parameter less constructor. I believe it is creating a new instance of my model class.

Comment: Can you be more specific / provide more information?

Comment: Can you include the code for your view?

Comment: @Jonesy I have added additional information

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I follow, but you can return the same view from your POST action, passing in the model. This will preserve the model data.

```c#
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CustomModel viewModel )
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here

        // The  button should trigger this method to   perform  update

        // Return "Create" view, with the posted model
        return View(model);
    }
    catch
    {
        // Do something useful to handle exceptions here.

        // Maybe add meaningful message to ViewData to inform user insert has failed?
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can put validation in your view and then use `ModelState.IsValid` property as  shown in below code :-

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CustomModel viewModel )
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                  ////Insert logic here
                  return RedirectToAction("Create");
                }

         return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "Get" method is returning a model that isn't present in your code(from what you have shown here). Below is a way to have your Action accept GET & POST.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get|HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(CustomModel viewModel)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here

        // The  button should trigger this method to   perform  update  

        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `create new instance` in your `Action Result` method.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // Assuming - First Time this ActioResult will be called.
    // After your other operations

    CustomModel model = new CustomModel();

    // Fill if any Data is needed
    return View(model);

    // OR - return new instance model here
    return View(new CustomModel());
}
```